# Tidy way of NA management by groups?

Tags: r, group-by, na, dplyr, tidy

my issue is the following:

I have a tibble which I want to modify with 3 different cases:

- All values in group are `NA`
- At least one but not all are `NA`. In this case replace `NA` with an arbitrary value (ex: `0.5`)
- None are `NA`

Example: (with `group_by` `ind`)

```
    a1 = c(0.3,0.1,NA,0.7,0.2)
    a2 = rep(NA,5)
    a3 = c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.8)
    tibble(ind = c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5),rep("C",5)),
       value = c(a1,a2,a3)
```

segment of group `A` should yield c(0.3,0.1,**0.5**,0.7,0.2)

segment of group `B` should yield rep(NA,5)

segment of group `C` should stay the same

I've tried with `if`, `ifelse` and `case_when` statements but I think I'm missing something very obvious. All help is appreciated.

Comment: So you just want to replace `NA` values in `a1` with 0.5?

Comment: Correct, however if the whole group is `NA` or none of them are keep all `NA`s or keep all values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

Here's a hack way to do it, though I know there is a more concise way:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ind) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.logical, as.numeric) %>% 
  mutate(a1 = case_when(is.na(a1) & sum(is.na(a1)) < length(a1) ~ 0.5, TRUE ~ a1),
         a2 = case_when(is.na(a2) & sum(is.na(a2)) < length(a2) ~ 0.5, TRUE ~ a2),
         a3 = case_when(is.na(a3) & sum(is.na(a3)) < length(a3) ~ 0.5, TRUE ~ a3))
```

Edit2: Here's the more concise way

```
point_five <- function(x){
  x = case_when(is.na(x) & sum(is.na(x)) < length(x) ~ 0.5, TRUE ~ x)
}

df %>%
  group_by(ind) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.logical, as.numeric) %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = c(a1:a3), ~ point_five(.)))
```

This gives us:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   ind [1]
  ind      a1    a2    a3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A       0.3    NA   0.1
2 A       0.1    NA   0.3
3 A       0.5    NA   0.5
4 A       0.7    NA   0.7
5 A       0.2    NA   0.8
```

If we have `df2`, containing two groups for `ind`, `group_by` will give us:

```
   ind      a1    a2    a3
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A       0.3    NA   0.1
 2 A       0.5    NA   0.3
 3 A       0.5    NA   0.5
 4 A       0.7    NA   0.7
 5 A       0.2    NA   0.8
 6 B       0.5    NA   0.1
 7 B       0.5    NA   0.3
 8 B       0.5    NA   0.5
 9 B       0.5    NA   0.7
10 B       0.2    NA   0.8
```

`df2`

```
structure(list(ind = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B"), a1 = c(0.3, 0.5, NA, 0.7, 0.2, NA, 0.5, NA, NA, 0.2
), a2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), a3 = c(0.1, 
0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I may have misexpressed myself. The 0.5 is not becuase it happens to be the last value, its an arbitrary number. Will edit for clarity.

Comment: Changed example for clarity

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `case_when`

```
df %>%
  group_by(ind) %>%
  mutate(value2 = case_when(
    !all(is.na(value)) & is.na(value) ~ 0.5,
    TRUE ~ value
  ))


#-----

# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   ind [3]
   ind   value value2
   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 A       0.3    0.3
 2 A       0.1    0.1
 3 A      NA      0.5
 4 A       0.7    0.7
 5 A       0.2    0.2
 6 B      NA     NA  
 7 B      NA     NA  
 8 B      NA     NA  
 9 B      NA     NA  
10 B      NA     NA  
11 C       0.1    0.1
12 C       0.3    0.3
13 C       0.5    0.5
14 C       0.7    0.7
15 C       0.8    0.8
```

Example data

```
a1 = c(0.3,0.1,NA,0.7,0.2)
a2 = rep(NA,5)
a3 = c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.8)
df <- tibble(ind = c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5),rep("C",5)),
             value = c(a1,a2,a3))
```